# Sound won't play in my app

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio

I have started on an app and I need an audio clip to play as soon as you start the app. This is my view controller.m file:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  audio test
//
//  Created by Kevin Patrick on 14/07/2012.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Team Tops. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)awakeFromNib {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                  pathForResource:@"CPOP MUSIC"ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                           initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
[theAudio play];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

@end
```

But when I simulate the app does not play any sound, it's blank and does nothing. I have got the audio file in the supporting files folder, I have seen something about the newest Xcode having issues but the file still won't play, I am a beginner so please go easy on me, thanks :)

Comment: ARC struct, you need put the AVAudioPlayer on a property, or will be released from memory then no play

Comment: Sorry, as i stated I am a beginner, so how would I do what you just said? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

http://mobileorchard.com/easy-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer/

Comment: Hello, thanks for a quick reply but i added the declaration above and still the audio doesn't play, is it a problem with my simulator?

Comment: maybe, check this http://mobileorchard.com/easy-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer/

Comment: OH MY!!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH I HAVE SPENT LIKE WEEKS TRYING TO GET SUCH A SIMPLE THING TO WORK, THANK YOU SO MUCH